# Trouble connecting to Oracle with c#

Tags: c#, oracle, database-connection

I have trouble connecting to an Oracle 11g XE instance that is running on a VM (on my local machine). 
I'm trying to connect to it with c# using:

```
using System.Data.OracleClient;
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("User Id=system;Password=mypassword;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.102)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=UDW))););
    oc.Open();
```

Error I'm getting is:

```
System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater.
```

Does this point to Oracle, or the version of the DLL?  Oracle is higher than 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it right, you need to install Oracle client and use Oracle.DataAccess.Dll that will be installed in that client directory under ODP.net directory. This is recommended way to connect to Oracle even though, Microsoft provides OleDb (not recommended to use) and `System.Data.OracleClient`. Microsoft recommendation is to use provider-native data connectivity. Oracle provides both clients, for x86 and x64. Using ODP.net allows for Oracle optimizations.

Comment: I downloaded as suggested and added Oracle.DataAccess.dll as a reference.  From my code I now just get a Oracle timeout, and from the Visual Studio Server Explorer it still shows "System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater.".  Any additional ideas?

Comment: Somehow, you need to remove any references to System.Data.OracleClient. May be it is in .config file. There must be a connection string that you've created, right? At the same time, you want to copy Oracle.DataAccess.Dll into your dependencies bin, depends, from where you get all your references, don't reference directly from Oracle installation folder.

Comment: THANKS!! The timeout was caused by the firewall on the Oracle server.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you need to update the oracle client library on your client machine.
download it [Oracle downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html)

Comment: Thanks.  Your link takes me to the Oracle full downloads.  Oracle is running on a different environment (VM).  Is that what you think the problem is, or should I rather try the client tools like: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html ?